# How do you deserialize JSON in java, using JSON.org

Tags: java, json, serialization, org.json

I am using "org.json" for JSON. I am able to serialize any class into a JSON string, using JSONObject. However, I'm not sure how to go the other way. How does one Deserialize a JSON string back into a class instance?

This code works to serialize it. I use JSONObject, and I provide a list of field names as a second argument to the constructor - User.JSONFieldMap().

```
    int randomValue = rnd.nextInt(10000);
    String userName = "JavaUnitTest_" + randomValue;
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.UserName = userName;
    newUser.DisplayName = "Java Unit Test";
    newUser.EmailAddress = userName + "@SomeDomainName.com";
    JSONObject jsonUser = new JSONObject(newUser, User.JSONFieldMap());
    String userStringified = jsonUser.toString();
```

I'm not sure how, or if it is possible to be able to do something like this:

```
    User myUser = MagicJSONDeserializer.DeserializeIt("{ some JSON string}");
```

Thanks for any help, I come from a .net/C#/Microsoft background, so Java is very new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That library does not provide such functionality directly. You can use any of hundreds of other Java JSON libraries that do, such as Gson, Jackson, or flexjson.

The *indirect* way of doing it would be to retrieve each value from the JSON and perform custom deserialization on that value before assigning it to an object field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was considering using Jackson. I hesitated because I am building an Android app, and I noticed that org.JSON is included with the Android SDK - so I wanted to stick with that.

Comment: @essedbl Jackson provides a lot of functionality. As such, it's relatively _big_. If your JSON is simple, other libraries may be more suitable.

Comment: @Sotirious: Thanks. I went to the git portal for Jackson, and I can't figure out how to get it... LOL... I will check out Gson... Thank you again!

Comment: @essedbl [Maven links](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) might be easier. You don't have to use maven, just download the library binaries.

Comment: Dude, thank you! I just downloaded Gson, and have it up an running serializing/deserializing my classes in just a couple minutes! I will look into Maven. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Update for someone interested in other solution. It can be achieved using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

String userStr = "{ \"NAME\" : \"John\" }";
User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(userStr, User.class);
```

It uses `ObjectMapper` to convert `byte[]` or in this case`String` to java object. This solution **needs to have** class `User` correctly annotated for example with `@JsonProperty` annotations. Otherwise it won't be able to match json key-values with class attributes.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;

public class User {
    @JsonProperty("NAME")
    String name;

    @JsonGetter("NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonSetter("NAME")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```